# Change dropdown value in JavaScript if session value is null

Tags: javascript, jsp

If there is no value in session, then I want to display **Select option**.

```
<select class="selectpicker show-tick" id="vehicle" data-live-search="true" required="required">
  <option data-tokens=""><%=session.getAttribute("operator1") %></option>
  <option data-tokens="Select option">Select option</option>
  <option data-tokens="car">Car</option>
  <option data-tokens="bike">Bike</option>
  <option data-tokens="truck">Truck</option>
```

Currently, it is displaying `null` if there is no value in the `Session`. I have used this code, but it is not working.

```
window.onload = function()
{
  var DropdownList = document.getElementById('vehicle');
  var SelectedIndex = DropdownList.selectedIndex;
  var SelectedValue = DropdownList.value;
  var SelectedText = DropdownList.options[DropdownList.selectedIndex].text;

        if (SelectedText == null)
        {
           DropDownList.SelectedValue == Select option;
        }
         else
        {
          // otherwise display session value
        }
}
```

Comment: So why output the element with the Java code in the first place? jstl or jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This you can achieve only by using ternary operator in JSP expression tag and avoid writing JavaScript.

Use:

```
<option data-tokens=""><%= session.getAttribute("operator1") != null ? session.getAttribute("operator1") : "Select option" %></option>
```

Remove:

```
<option data-tokens="Select option">Select option</option>
```

Comment: Can you help me with how to display placeholder if session value is null in textarea.       `    <input type="tel" id="tel" value="<%=session.getAttribute("mob1") %>" placeholder="Enter number" required="required" />    `

Comment: You can ask new question, I'll see what code you have written and how that can be make to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just in-case if you wondered why your code did not work, there are several cases you should focus,

```
window.onload = function() {
      var DropdownList = document.getElementById('vehicle');
      var SelectedIndex = DropdownList.selectedIndex;
      var SelectedValue = DropdownList.value;
      var SelectedText = DropdownList.options[DropdownList.selectedIndex].text;

        if (SelectedText == null) { // this might actually not work as you think, in case you might need to use `"null"`
           // DropDownList.SelectedValue == Select option;
           DropDownList.value = "Select option";
        } else {
             // otherwise display session value
        }
 }
```

Regarding,

```
<input type="tel" id="tel" value="<%=session.getAttribute("mob1") %>" placeholder="Enter number" required="required" />
```

Did you try,

```
<input type="tel" id="tel" value="<%=session.getAttribute("mob1") != null ? session.getAttribute("mob1") : "" %>" placeholder="Enter number" required="required" />
```

Comment: Sorry I just changed it with some minor changes.

Comment: yes, but it displayed "Enter number" as value, not placeholder.

Comment: @Amanjit Ah got it. Then you can just mention an empty string if the value is null. So the place holder will take effect. See the updated answer.

Comment: Oh yes, it worked perfectly fine. thank you for helping me out.